# how to pause in a loop of "read line"

Tags: bash

I know that
(1) I can loop through lines of a file with

```
while read line  
do  
    something  
done < file
```

(2) I can pause my program with

```
something  
read -p "press any key to continue..."  ## pause here waiting for key in  
something
```

However, the pause trick does not work in a read line loop like this

```
while read line  
do  
    something  
    read -p "press any key to continue..."  ## suppose to pause here  
done < file
```

So why is that and how to get over it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your read command also reads from stdin (from your file).

With Linux you can use this:

```
read -p "press any key to continue..." < /dev/tty
```

Comment: One downside with this is that you now can't bypass the pausing with `./script </dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
exec 3< words
while read -u 3 word; do
    printf 'Got "%s"\n' "$word"
    read -p 'Press enter.'
done
```

This starts off by opening file descriptor 3 (unused by the shell ordinarily) and sends the contents of the file `words` to it.

The `read` then reads from this file descriptor (`-u 3`) and the loop displays the result and waits for input from the user on standard input.

---

The reason that you loop does not work is that you redirect the input of *both* `read` calls from the file. Anything that reads from standard input in your loop will get data from the file.