# read Statement not working in Linux script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have a script in linux. The read statements in a while loop does not work. I have made many tries but to no avail. Here is my code:

```
while read instanceInFile
do
    echo -e "$instanceInFile"
    read -sp "Enter Password for the instance: " paswrd
    mysql -uauser -p$paswrd -e "create user '$user'@'$ip' identified by '$user';"
done<"allInstances.out"
```

> allInstances.out

is a file containing list of environment scripts to run. when i run the script it show the below error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'power-user'@'some-ip' (using password: YES)
```

while it does not read from the user.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46021410/3776858

Answer (score 1):

The two `read` commands are both consuming the same stream. You can have the first `read` access a different file descriptor:

```sh
while read -r instanceInFile <&3; do
   .... while body unchanged
done 3< allInstances.out
```

---

original answer probably does not apply:

> The code formatting in your question is off. Do you really have
>
> ```sh
> ...
> done <myfile >myfile
> ```
>
> ??
>
> bash processes redirections **before** invoking the command. The output redirection `>` will **truncate** the file to zero bytes **before** the while read loop starts. Therefore, the while loop has **no lines** to read.
>
> You need to do
>
> ```sh
> ...; done <myfile >tempfile && mv tempfile myfile
> ```
>
> or, with the miscutils package
>
> ```sh
> ...; done <myfile | sponge myfile
> ```